# error while multiplying columns of dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with s_df and r_df. There is a column l1 in s_df and column l2 in r_df which have positive and negative real numbers. I am trying to do something if the pairwise product of these columns is positive. Like

```
if ((s_df['l1']*r_df['l2']) > 0):
    print " do something"
```

But I get the error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I don't understand this error

Comment: Define what you mean by "product of these columns is positive". As per the answers, there are 3 meanings: any of the pairwise products are positive, all of the pairwise products are positive, or perform some calculation for each pairwise positive product.

Comment: I have down-voted this question based on the above uncertainty, happy to upvote when it is clarified.

Comment: just clarified my question. I want the pairwise product between the two columns

Comment: Sorry, we are going round in circles. Now define "pairwise product between the two columns". There's an easy way to help us. Make up 2 columns of 3 numbers and tell us what you want as the output.

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply 2 columns, the result will be also a column containing several elements. Each element could be positive or negative. The `if` in this case is referred to the new series, not on each element, so it is not possible to have a not ambiguous result.

Try with(probably not the most pythonic way):

```
for index, row in s_df.iterrows():
    for index1, row1 in r_df.iterrows():
        if (s_df['l1']*r_df['l2']) > 0:
            print "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding sum() method you are doing the sum of the product of your 2 vectors :

```
if(s_df['l1'] * s_df['l2']).sum() > 0:
    print("something")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the expression is not fully defined. Here are some options that the suggest:

All items in the DFs are > than 0:
if ((s_df['l1']*r_df['l2']).all() > 0):

Any item in the DFs is > than 0:
if ((s_df['l1']*r_df['l2']).any() > 0):

If you want it to walk through every row, you may want to use itertools.